# hg diff local to remote file

Tags: mercurial

This may be a silly question but when comparing a local to remote file, what is the path to the remote file?
Does hg want you to provide the head/revision you are referring to or something?

ie:

```
hg diff /local/file /remote?/file?
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mercurial doesn't do this.  The only comparison with other repositories is `hg incoming` and `hg outgoning` which show which changesets differ between repositories.  You can add the `--patch` option to either of those to see the patches that are the meat of those changesets, but you can't compare two versions of a file without having them in the same local clone.

Answer (score 1):

From [Hg man](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#diff)

```
hg diff [OPTION]... ([-c REV] | [-r REV1 [-r REV2]]) [FILE]...
```

I am not sure if you can speak about a "remote file" in a DVCS: you need to fetch or clone a remote repo in order to be able to make any `hg diff`.
`hg fetch`, for instance, is [described here](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-merging-work.html#sec%3atour-merge%3afetch).

Comment: Fetch is really recommended against these days.  One should use `pull`, and if you just can't stand two steps `pull -u`.

Comment: @Ry4an: agreed, and +1 on your answer.